# Apache Karaf OSGI app with large number of import dependencies

Tags: dependencies, osgi, karaf

I've just deployed my first Karaf app, having converted it over from a Tomcat war file.  What I've noticed is that there's a large number of dependencies for Karaf but a small number for Tomcat.

In Karaf, how can I do away with the extra dependencies? In CQ, there is a "negative import list". Is there something similar for Karaf?

Comment: I don´t understand what you are trying to achieve or where your problem is. Your application should not depend on karaf itself. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I had not yet discovered negative dependencies.